# Is low frequency sound slower (in air)?

Tags: waves, acoustics, dispersion, ultrasound

Does sound in air experience dispersion? In other words, is the group velocity of sound higher for higher frequencies or the other way round? Is this difference substantial enough to be noticed/heard?

This is an attempt to put on more serious footing this question: [Does it take longer for low-frequency sounds to reach a listener?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289447/247642).

I didn't find much info about the sound dispersion in Wikipedia, however, [this page](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Dispersion+of+Sound) suggests the following relation:
$$
c^2=c_0^2+(c_{\infty}^2-c_0^2)\frac{\omega^2\tau^2}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}.$$

Comment: look for phonon dispersion relation in air. [This article](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.2947631#:~:text=A%20general%20expression%20for%20the%20dispersion%20of%20acoustic,sound%20velocity%20at%20different%20frequencies%20and%20relative%20humidities.) should give you what you need? Long story short, it's pretty much constant (tho it depends on which precision you're looking for). It doesn't vary by more than 0.1m/s according to the data in the results section (0.03% variation in speed won't be perceived by a human ear I suppose)

Comment: Barbaud Julien is right. Air, like all media is dispersive in the absolute sense of the term. Nevertheless, the dispersion is so low for "normal" conditions in the audible frequency bandwidth that it is omitted with negligible effects.

Comment: @ZaellixA it well could be an answer, if someone exands it a bit and adds the estimates.

Comment: @RogerVadim I will do my best to provide some more info on what I know about it when I find some more time (super busy at the moment). I wonder if this paper (https://www.sfu.ca/~dgnapier/sound-2008.pdf) can be of any help. I have only read the abstract and I don't have the necessary background to understand it, but you may be able to get something out of it. Additionally, the information in the page you linked seems quite right to me, based on what little I know about dispersion in sound (it is a non-linear process and I have only used linear acoustics so far). For more information (cont.)

Comment: you may want to consult Fundamentals of Acoutics by Kinsler et al. or Introduction to Acoustics by Kuttruff. You can only find some "lightweight" information about that in those texts but I don't have a better suggestion at the moment, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**: The comments are correct; dispersion is technically present but nearly imperceptible.  However, strictly speaking the group velocity does increase with frequency.

**Detailed Discussion**:

According to Blackstock's book *Fundamentals of Physical Acoustics*, the wavenumber in a viscous fluid (thermal effects are accounted for in a nearly identical manner for constant frequency signals, and are of the same order as viscous effects) may be written as
$$ k = \frac{\omega/c_0}{\sqrt{1+i\tilde V\delta_v\omega}}, $$
where $k$ is the wavenumber, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $c_0$ is the inviscid wave speed, $\tilde V=O(1)$ is the viscosity number, and $\delta_v=\nu/c_0^2$, with $\nu$ being the kinematic viscosity.  For standard conditions $\delta_{v_{air}}\approx 1.3\times10^{-10}$ s.  Taking the derivative of $k$ with respect to $\omega$ yields the inverse of the group velocity, $c_g$, and so we may write
$$c_g = \left(\frac{\partial k}{\partial\omega}\right)^{-1} = c_0\frac{2(1+i\tilde V\delta_v\omega)^{3/2}}{2+i\tilde V\delta v\omega}.$$
The imaginary part is associated with losses, so we want to focus on the real part.  Noting that $\delta_v\omega$ is going to be very small compared to 1 or 2 for any signal of consideration, we may expand this function and write
$$\Re\left\{\frac{c_g}{c_0}\right\} = 1 + \frac{\tilde V^2\delta_v^2\omega^2}{8} + O(\delta_v^4\omega^4).$$
Thus, the group velocity does indeed become larger with frequency.  However, the increase is negligible for all frequencies of interest.  For example, ultrasound can go as high as the megahertz, so lets go even higher and use $\omega=10^{7}$ s$^{-1}$.  Then we may write the increase of the group velocity from the zero-frequency limit as being on the order of $(10^{-10}\cdot10^{7})^2c_0=10^{-6}c_0$.  This is on the order of millimeters per second compared to hundreds of meters per second.  Slight fluctuations of the ambient temperature have a far more profound effect than the dispersion of the air.