# Why does not the speed of sound in air depend on frequency and wavelength?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, wavelength, dispersion

I have read that *speed of longitudinal waves depends upon the frequency and wavelength* and, but why it doesn't happen with sound waves in air?

And if velocity of sound doesn't depend upon the frequency and wavelength in air why is not same in the case of solid medium?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is low frequency sound slower (in air)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/690683/)

Comment: This is not precisely what I want to ask

Comment: It is literally about whether the speed of sound depends on frequency/wavelength: the answer is *yes*, but the dependence is too weak to make difference in most cases.